# WordPress make post sticky via script?

Tags: wordpress

```
    // Create post objects
    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['post_title'] = 'Main Blog Post Title';
    $my_post['post_content'] = 'Main Blog Post Content';
    $my_post['post_type'] = 'post';


    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

How can I make this post sticky via the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
stick_post($post_id);
```